# Updating a live line graph on a web page with values from java application

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, web-services

I have a java application running on PC X and a web application [javascript+html+bootstrap] on tomcat server on PC Y.

The java application has two variables in a class which are distance and Time which are constantly changing at a frequency. In the web application I need to plot a line graph [speed] of these values on a browser opened at any PC A by a user. It should be something close to what stock market graphs look like

I am a relative novice in web programming though I know a little bit of java. How can I send the values from the java application to my web application?

When I search this I get terms like web services, ajax, json, servlets etc. Its more confusing than helpful.

How should I proceed?

My html page is just containing one panel inside which I want to display the graph.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is ajax, JSON, servlets.

Ajax in your javascript to make the HTTP request to your server from the browser.

JSON as the encoding you will use to return the data.

Servlet in your Java code to respond to the HTTP request and send back the JSON data. You will likely want to use a library to create your JSON data, Gson is a good choice.

I suggest finding a tutorial on java servlets as a starting point and settle in as there is plenty to learn.

Comment: Thank You...I have started with servlets.